# AWS Database Structures - MySQL & DynamoDB

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking to run a DynamoDB database for my transational data and a mysql database for data the needs SQL Join Queries.

To try to keep bulk/large tables out of MySQL (keeping performance better) I'm going to move some data into DynamoDB that will sometimes need to referenced against data in MySQL.

Is it poor programming/querying to query DynamoDB for certain data and query MySQL and then in PHP (or another server side language) perform a final data comparison to get the required data to return to the client/browser?

I guess the base question is: Having to query a NoSQL & SQL databases to then cruch a result in php (or a server side language)... is this normal or a bad idea?

thx

Note: main purpose of this is database planning to avoid an unmanageable over-large relational database situation. Thus want to move bulk data to NoSQL (DynamoDB)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a very good idea to separate your data to different data stores, each with its benefits.

For example:

- you can put BLOB in your RDBMS (as MySQL), but it is better to have in a storage as [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).
- You can put text documents in your RDBMS and query them with "... LIKE %QUERY%...", but it is better to put them in Elastic Search or [Amazon CloudSearch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/).
- You can put your session management data in your RDBMS, but it is better to have in [Amazon Elastic Cache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) or [DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/)
- You can have your lookup tables in RDBMS, but it is better to have in memory or memory based NoSQL (as Memecached or Redis) or DynamoDB

And you can write the above statements differently, storing everything in MongoDB or DynamoDB, but preferring to put them elsewhere.

When you are putting your data in different stores, based on the simplicity of this data store related to the type of data and your usage of this data, you can get a simpler, distributed, scalable and usually faster system.

The downside is that you need to sync your data among the data stores. Once you add a record to your DynamoDB, you need to upload the BLOB to S3, update the document in CloudSearch and add the record to your MySQL, as well as write the relevant lines to your log file for future analysis. This is, of course, the extreme case to having such a complex data and queries on it. Usually you only need to mix 2 or 3 data stores.

If you must have transactions in your system, it will be much more difficult to sync your data, and it is better to have all your data in a data store that supports transactions. But even then, you can limit your transactions requirement to part of your data and live with redundant data in other data stores. For example, having orphan S3 objects that have no reference record in your RDBMS or DynamoDB, is not a big problem usually.

Regarding having PHP (or other programming language) code that you are writing to manipulate the distributed data, it also depends. If you need complex JOIN, GROUP_BY, FILTER functionality that is natively supported by the data store, it is better to use the DB functionality. But many times, your code can be simple enough to write, like querying the right DB (for example, textual search to CloudSearch) and assemble the data pieces from across your different data stores.

Answer (score 1):

yes u can surely use the both...
but there are some pros and cons for it..
**CONS :**

- In MySQL you'll get ACID guarantee, but in Dynamo-db there is no such guarantee.
- Also in MySQL you can write complex  while in Dynamo-db you can't write complex queries.

**PROS :**

- It has the property of distributed hash tables hence more performance booster as compared to MySQL.

you need to look at this blog for more information .
Here's [a link](HTTP://highscalability.com/blog/2010/12/21/sql-nosql-yes.html)!

you can also use more NoSql modules like HIVEQL.
HiveQl is much more than Dynamo-Db it can boost performance bit more than Dynamo-db.